# Trying to delete a site that has been created via a template issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Once again another issue

I am trying to delete a site that i have created via a template and i am running in to

> No available sandboxed code execution server could be found.

The template only contains a few columns programatically created along with some content types.

The CT's are also added to lists.

Anyone got any ideas?

I will continue to go through the ULS logs and hope someone saves me

Cheers
        Truez

Comment: Do you have features with feature receivers there?

Comment: Yes but from what i am aware they have no code in them. I placed the reciever there as a precaution as things are ever changing. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty receivers in your features and your solution is a SANDBOX one you should either switch it to Farm solution or check if your user code host service is running. Go to Services and check the "SharePoint 2010 User Code Host". Also check the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" service in the /_admin/Server.aspx It has to be running to support sandbox solutions.

Comment: Going to give this a whirl and i will get back to you :)

Comment: My solution isn't a sandboxed solution :S

Comment: OK. You need to start the SharePoint Foundation Sandbox Code Service service instance from services on server..

Comment: We couldn't find the service. The way I managed to get around it was recreate the site collection and there was no issue. Thanks for the heads up. Just for future reference is this service located where the other standard services for sharepoint are located?